# Replacing missing data with interpolation values

Tags: r, interpolation, imputation

I was searching information about filling missing values with interpolation and I found three most important ones. So there are :

(1) Linear Interpolation

(2) Spline Interpolation

(3) Stineman Interpolation

Can you please share with me algorithms behind those ? I was searching on internet something about using them to fill missing data and I couldn't find anything about Spline or Stineman interpolation. Is there any way how can we use polynomial interpolation to estimate missing values ? I couldn't find also an R code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Package for Stineman Interpolation: `stinepack`.
And function for Spline Interpolation: `splinefun`